# Generic handler (ashx) not rising with jquery autocomplete plugin

Tags: jquery, asp.net, handler, jquery-autocomplete, generic-handler

My generic handler is not being called when using autocomplete,

I have this in my .aspx page.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $("#test").autocomplete("Handlers/MyHandler.ashx");
 }
```

with this files included jquery-1.4.2.min.js and jquery-ui-1.8.custom.min.js

I put a breakpoint on server never is reached, also used firebug to see if jquery is making its request and nothing, could be a bug with the plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not initializing the jQuery ui autocomplete properly, pass a object with a source property:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $("#test").autocomplete({source: "Handlers/MyHandler.ashx"});
 }
```

Passing a string directly is used to access one of its methods, for example:

```
$("#test").autocomplete("enable");
```

Comment: @the-scrum-meister thanks that works!! BTW do you know how to pass a key value pair as result to the autocomplete.

Comment: @user468526 The autocomplete accepts `label` and `value` property, I would suggest looking into a Json formatted for .net.